# loopback PersistedModel find() error handling

Tags: node.js, error-handling, loopbackjs

I'm following loopback framework tutorial, specifically this page
https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Extend+your+API
there is an example code that finds an instance by ID, I modified it a bit to handle non-existent instances

```
Coffeeshop.getName=function(id, cb)
{
    Coffeeshop.findById(id, function(err, shop){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            cb(err);
        }
        else                
            cb(null, 'Name of the coffee shop is '+shop.name);
    });
};
```

It all works fine when I call it with existing ID, however when I enter an invalid ID, instead of calling the `err` handler it's omitted entirely, the `else` statement is called and the whole app crashes with the following console error

```
/app/path/here/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:78
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
```

I'm new to node.js and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here but shouldn't the error be passed into the callback function rather than being thrown to the top level?

This doesn't seem to be mysql backend specific, I switched to mongo connector and got a similar problem. How to handle an error like this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check `shop` parameter also. A complete check would be like this:

```
Coffeeshop.getName=function(id, cb)
{
    Coffeeshop.findById(id, function(err, shop){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            cb(err);
        }
        else
        {
          if(shop) {
            cb(null, 'Name of the coffee shop is '+shop.name);
          } else {
            var error = new Error();
            error.message = 'Coffee Shop is not found.';
            error.statusCode = 404;
            cb(error);
          }
        }           

    });
};
```

Here is a pattern that loopback uses for their built-in models. Code is from the file `node_modules/loopback/common/models/user.js`, at around 281 line number.

```
User.logout = function(tokenId, fn) {
fn = fn || utils.createPromiseCallback();
this.relations.accessTokens.modelTo.findById(tokenId, function(err, accessToken) {
  if (err) {
    fn(err);
  } else if (accessToken) {
    accessToken.destroy(fn);
  } else {
    fn(new Error('could not find accessToken'));
  }
});
return fn.promise;
```

Comment: thanks, that approach worked. I was confused by mysql exception, I expected it to be passed as `err` parameter to my callback. do you by any chance know when this parameter will be used? if there will be a query error or somehing like this?

Comment: Server disconnected will through this error for sure. Don't know for `findById` but for methods like `create`, validations errors and for `User.login`, login failed error will be reported through this.